# SVG & HTML: getBBox and getBoundingClientRect not the same as when hover over node in inspector

Tags: javascript, html, svg

So I have an `<g>` tag in an svg element with a `clip-path` that consists of a rectangle defined by `{x:0,y:0,width:1000,height;800}`. I added the clipping path as I wanted to hide some overflown children of this tag.

When I select this tag and call either `getBBox()` or `getBoundingClientRect()` for some reason I get the rectangle of the clipping path - not the dimensions of the overflow.

This is strange for two reasons:

1. mouse-over the element in the browser inspector (mozilla and chrome) shows the correct dimensions (`width:1200, height:800`).
2. in a similarly structured document, these methods return the dimensions with overflow.

So what is the correct behavior? and how do I get the full width of an svg element with clip-path hidden elements?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the [SVG 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#clipPath-geometry) and the [CSS masking spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1/#clipping-paths) state this:

> A clipping path affects the rendering of an element. It does not affect the element’s inherent geometry. The geometry of a clipped element (i.e. an element which references a `<clipPath>` element via a `clip-path` property, or a child of the referencing element) must remain the same as if it were not clipped.r

And this is what happens in the example below. So this might not be what your result is about.

Note that the results for `.getBBox()` and `.getBoundingClientRect()` differ. That is because the first states size in the local userpace coordinate system, while the latter states size in screen pixels. It might not be obvious that a transformation has been taking place between the two, as it might be hidden implicitely in the relation between `viewBox`, `width` and `height` attributes of the `<svg>` element.

```js
const clipped = document.querySelector('#clipped');
const bbox = clipped.getBBox();
console.log(bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height);
const bcrect = clipped.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(bcrect.x, bcrect.y, bcrect.width, bcrect.height);
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <clipPath id="cp">
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" />
  </clipPath>
  <rect id="clipped" width="200" height="200" clip-path="url(#cp)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer and I am aware of the difference between BBox and BoundingClientRect  but my issue is that both BBox and BoundingClientRect return a width that is too small...

Comment: more impressive still, is that if I select an <g> with objects inside this clipping path, now - instead of getting a rect with a width that is somewhat too small, I get a rect with 0 width.

Comment: This fiddle has the same structure that I am using and shows that BBox and BoundingClientRect should work https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/g2vkb7dz/ however at https://sumneuron.gitlab.io/d3sm/demos/bar-chart-same-data-complex-grouping/index.html it does not

Comment: I am not familiar with d3sm, but I am pretty sure now that you simply log the size at a time when the chart is not yet populated. Probably the `.valueExtractor()` function that draws the bars executes the callback asynchronuously? That also explains the 0 result for the group: the rect is not yet inside. You can test by two means: 1. execute the `.getBBox()` directly from the console after the page has finished loading, and you will get the right results. 2. Try selecting the `<rect>` directly instead of the enclosing group in your script. I think you will find the selection is empty.

Comment: thank you for that informative insight. I think I know the issue... animations (or more specifically transitions). Transitions - in my experience - can interfere with DOM queries as well as properties of the transitioning elements. the function .valueExtractor() is called synchronous to my knowledge (as the bars are rendered) as this is what is needed to scale the values.

Comment: interestingly, however, is that if I call `selectAll('rect')` in the same `console.log` as but before I call `getBBox` I get a list of rects. So either they exist at that point (which would be against what you suggest) or the console later populates once they exist, which I do not thing is correct?

Comment: `b.selection().selectAll("rect").nodes().map(function(d, i){console.log(d.getBoundingClientRect(), i)})` but calling this right before the log of the bbox and bounding rect gives me a list of rects, all with no width and height. So I think the chart is populated, but the animation for width and height have not been complete. However, if I set the transition duration to 0 I still have no values... so I honestly have no idea what is going on... but plus 1 for the assistance

Comment: A transition duration of 0 might not mean synchronuous execution - If I was implementing such a thing, I would, for simplicities sake, just set the end value in the first available async call.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I follow, do you mean something like `myRect.attr('transform','translate('+finalX+','+finalY+')').transition().duration(0).attr('transform','translate('+startX+','+startY+')').transition().duration(durationTime).attr('transform','translate('+finalX+','+finalY+')')` ??

Comment: I'll go with the assumption that `.transition()` is the function from d3.js. This sets up a timer, even if the duration is then set to 0. On transition start, one frame for running the transition in is requested (see https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/src/transition/schedule.js#L82, which ultimately calls https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/blob/master/src/timer.js#L39). The `.requestAnimationFrame()` is asynchronuous. Only on running its callback, the transition reaches the conclusion that the end time has been reached, sets the end value and stops the animation.

Comment: ok so now I know how this is messing things up and I greatly appreciate that you have helped me so much so far (especially as you have stated your unfamiliarity with d3 so far). Do you think it is possible to set and use the end value with this transition? or not possible?

Comment: I said I am not familiar with d3sm, d3.js I know well enough. You can listen for the end of a transition with `transition.on('end'`, ...)` if that is what you meant. See https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#the-life-of-a-transition

Comment: :/ that is rather annoying... as it makes selectors unreliable if I want to use transitions. Is there a way to grab an ongoing transition? It really makes it hard to modularize code if you also want transitions...